# Asciidoctor: how to replace expression in included document?

Tags: asciidoctor

Given asciidoctor file `my-document.adoc` with the content:

```
include::included-document.adoc[]
```

`included-document.adoc` contains

```
The content of this file cannot be changed.

This text *has to be replaced*.
```

When I render `my-document.adoc`, I want to have the visible content

The content of this file cannot be changed.
This text **has successfully been replaced**.

Is this possible without changing `included-document.adoc`? `my-document.adoc` may be changed.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you'd have to write a custom extension to handle the change during the include. Maybe a bit more info or concrete example would help.

Comment: @LightGuard: I have added some information.

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to create a custom extension to do the include and any processing to the included document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an Asciidoctor extension lab that provides examples for this, for example an include processor that exchanges tabs for spaces.

I hope this gets you started.

https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-extensions-lab/blob/master/lib/whitespace-include-processor.rb